# Расширение HTML input элемента

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Делаю компонент, который просто расширяет обычный html input.

```
const Input: React.FC<HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (...props }) => <input {...props}} />
```

Логика достаточно простая, беру обычный html input, делаю компонент и прокидываю пропсы. В целом, все пропсы нормально прокидываются (placeholder, value, onChange, className и т.д.), но возникает проблема с пропом `type`.

При попытке назначения типа в компоненте `<Input type="text" />` возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

В общем, что-то я делаю не так, но не пойму что именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку, вдруг кому-то пригодится.

Для расширения должен использоваться не `HTMLAttributes`, а `InputHTMLAttributes`
В итоге получается:

```
const Input: React.FC<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (...props }) => <input {...props}} />
```

Либо, в случае расширения через свой интерфейс

```
interface ICustom extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
myProp: any
}

const Input: React.FC<ICustom> = (myProps, ...props }) => <input {...props}} />
```